# Erro http 419 laravel-cors?

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, cors

Para corrigir a falha de cors na api laravel eu me utilizei o pacote [Laravel Cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) e segui tudo o que era informado no *readme*, porem agora está me retornando um erro ao realizar uma requisição `http` `post`

***Erro:***

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/hqi/palestra 419 (unknown status)

`Controller` referente a requisição:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $palestras_divulgacao = new palestras_divulgacao;
    $palestras_divulgacao->fill($request->all());
    $palestras_divulgacao->save();
    return response()
            ->json($palestras_divulgacao, 201);
}
```

Chamada `http` `post` **Angular** no lado do cliente:

```
public registrarPalestra(p: palestras): Observable<number> {
    let headers: Headers = new Headers()
    headers.append('Content-type', 'aplication\json')

    return this.http.post(
      `${URL_API}palestra`,
      JSON.stringify(p),
      new RequestOptions({headers: headers})
    ).pipe(map(response => response.json().id));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deve ser a parte da proteção [CSRF](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf) que deve ser configurada no arquivo `app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`, dentro da configuração `$except` a rota `hqi/*` para liberar essa rota dessa verificação, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{        
    protected $except = [
        'hqi/*',
    ];
}
```

---

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [CSRF Protection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf)
- [Excluding Routes from the CSRF Middleware](https://laravel-news.com/excluding-routes-from-the-csrf-middleware)

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda